# What would be the right syntax in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery function which on submit event is generating an url.If one the parameter is not defined, adding to url should be skipped

```
        var category        =$("#prod_category").val();
        var group           =$("#prod_group")
        window.location.href = "/page/" +
            **//add to url if category is definned**
        encodeURI(category) + "/" +
            **//add to url if group is definned**       
        encodeURI(group) + "/" +
```

Comment: Worth noting that you are looking for vanilla javascript syntax - there is no need to use jQuery for an `if` statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply state `if (category)`. If `category` has a value with a length greater than zero, this will return `true`.

```
var url = "/page/";
if (category){
  url = url + encodeURI(category) + "/";
}
if (group){
  url = url + encodeURI(group) + "/";
}
```

**EDIT:** When setting the values to `category` and `group` ensure you trim any whitespace that the element may be containing. For example:

```
var category = $.trim($("#prod_category").val());
```

Comment: in form elements the elements do exist. Thats why simple check is not enough. In this case jquery will return empty value, and if its a space then what will you do?

Comment: @ZahidRiaz I've seen your answer and I understand what you are saying, but I don't believe that is the correct place to `trim`. The object `category` should either be blank or the correct value. It's called `category`, not `prod_category_val`. Therefore it should be a category name, already validated. Trimming should occur before this if statement. I'll edit my answer to mention this, but I don't believe it deserves a downvote.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using $.grep:

```
var category = $.trim($("#prod_category").val());
var group = $.trim($("#prod_group").val());
window.location.href = '/page/' + $.grep([category, group], function(s) { return s != null && s.length }).join('/');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var category =$.trim( $("#prod_category").val() );
var group    =$.trim( $("#prod_group").val() );
var urlVal = "/page/";
if( category !== "") {
  urlVal += encodeURI(category);
}
if( group !== "") {
 urlVal += encodeURI(group);
}
window.location.href = urlVal;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
if($.trim(category) != ''){
}
if($.trim(group) != ''){
}
```